# CSS transition not applied on SVG elements in Google Chrome

Tags: php, css, google-chrome, svg

So I have a bunch of SVG icons in a version of my nav bar, but for some reason the CSS transition time that I am using is not being applied.  This is happening in Chrome, IE, and Safari.  It works well in Firefox/Nightly and Opera/Opera Next.

Here is the CSS that is not working

```
CSS:
#liIco
{
    fill: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: fill .5s;
       -moz-transition: fill .5s;
         -o-transition: fill .5s;
            transition: fill .5s;
}

 a:hover #liIco
{
    fill: #000;
    -webkit-transition: fill .5s;
       -moz-transition: fill .5s;
         -o-transition: fill .5s;
            transition: fill .5s;
}
```

Here is a fiddle, though ironically enough it works in here: http://jsfiddle.net/FwKQe/1/

I think the problem may be that in my actual file I am using PHP to include the files like this ...

PHP(actual source from my file):

```
<aside id="sideContent">

    <div id="menuButton">

        <?php include ("icons/menu_w.svg"); ?>

    </div>

    <!-- This is the main NAV block -->


    <a href="index.php"><div id="imgHome"><?php include ("icons/home.svg"); ?></div></a>
    <a href="about.php"><div id="imgAbout"><?php include ("icons/about.svg"); ?></div></a>
    <a href="portfolio.php"><div id="imgWork"><?php include ("icons/work.svg"); ?></div></a>
```

One more note, the menu button at the top works all the time, and it is also a PHP include, so I'm sorta lost.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are including some invalid code when you use `include("image.svg")`, because it also includes an XML declaration and a DOCTYPE, which are illegal to be included anywhere other than at the beginning of a document. This may mess the structure (the browser falls back on parse errors and creates an seemingly unexpected structure) and cause issues, so try getting rid of invalid code first.

Comment: Did the code in your fiddle come from you constructing it manually.  Or did you copy and paste the source from the "View Source" screen in your browser?  If it was the former, try the latter. :)

Comment: Note that in some cases, "View source" may not always yield the exact, untouched response from the server. :(

Comment: The source code was copied from my original files. Also, I went through the original files and removed the doctype declaration and the XML data.  Still not working. Also, I copied the source code over from  the "view source" option in chrome. Again, works in JSfiddle, but not in Chrome browser proper.

Comment: Does the console show something? Also, if you could put that page on a server (maybe an iFrame is behaving differently and JSFiddle is using iFrames and some sort of configuration) so we could see it live, it may help.